# Error con encode64 PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base64, blob

Verán, después de revisar durante horas y horas alguna solución para mostrar una imagen en PHP del tipo blob no me la muestra. He aquí el código:

```
<?php 
    $cons=ct('SELECT * from imagenes where id_ev_im='.$_GET['id']);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cons);
?>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf8;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['imagen_im']);?>"/>
```

Asi guardo la imagen:

```
  <?php
  $id= $_GET['id'];
$datos = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
if(!empty($datos))  {
            $insertar = insert('imagenes','NULL,'.$id.',"'.$datos.'"');
            if ($insertar) {?> 
        <script type="text/javascript">alert('La imagen ha sido subida.');</script>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=panel_evento.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
  <?php
        } else {
              ?>
               <script type="text/javascript">alert('Error al subir la imagen.');</script>
               <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=panel_evento.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
        <?php
  }
}else{
      ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">alert('¡Error! No ha seleccionado ninguna imagen.');</script>
      <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=panel_evento.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
<?php
      
}  
      ?>
```

CT es una función en mi archivo de conexión (ya incluido en la página con include) que ejecuta tal cual la sentencia sql. El resultado de la etiqueta img solo me da el icono por defecto de imagen.
Estaría agradecido de que me aclararan dónde está mi error o por qué no me aparece la imagen. Todo va dentro de un archivo php con html5.

Comment: Cuando almacenas el blob de imagen en `imagen_im` como almacenas?

Comment: Uso un input de tipo file que direcciona a otra página php. La imagen en la página php la guardo con $datos = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])); 
Y únicamente la inserto a mi tabla. Los parametros de la tabla son: id_imagen, id_evento (foránea) y la imagen de tipo mediumblob.

Comment: Entonces lo almacenas con encode, por lo que para mostrarla debes usar decode; intenta `<?php echo base64_decode($row['imagen_im']);?>`

Comment: Al cambiarlo a decode me apareció ahora el icono más caracteres no definidos.

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega la sección del código de como guardas la imagen en BD. Te invito a revisar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Listo, editada.

Comment: Si al guardar la imagen en la base de datos ya la guardas codificada con `base64_encode`, ¿no tendrías que meterla en el `IMG` sin aplicarle ya ninguna transformación? (ni `base64_encode` ni `base64_decode`).

Comment: En efecto, no tenía contemplado eso y solo era mostrarlo en la etiqueta img. Has resuelto mi gran problema. Muy agradecido.